# How to get the classpath resource basename of a config file in Spring proejct?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, config

In my Spring proejct, I created a `config.conf` to store some variables.

And in a class I need to read these variables.

I am using the `config` library, https://github.com/lightbend/config.

And as the document says, I tried to used

```
private static final Config config = ConfigFactory.load(basename here goes here);
```

to load that `config.conf` file.

And by the document, https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.html#load-java.lang.String-, this method receives a string as classpath resource basename.

I am wondering how to get this "classpath resource basename" of the `config.conf` file?

My project's structure:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access file like this.

```
URL url = EmailService.class.getClassLoader().getResource("config.conf");
```

to load config, you can access path like below

```
config.load(url.getPath());
```